# Using BufferedReader in JSP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

so I'm using JSP for the first time and I came across a problem using a BufferReader from a Java class on a JavaScript function.

```
 function getLine(){
      var line;
      var l2;
      var c=0;
      while (c<10){ 
             line = "<%=client.is.readLine()%>"
             console.log(line);
             c++;
      }
```

I was expecting that for each different cycle that I'd get a different line value but the thing is that I'm always getting the first line on my console from the different lines available to read. Have in mind that the "client" object represents an instance of a Java class that is imported on this JSP file and that the "is" object represents an instance of a BufferReader. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but JSP was released in 1999 and pretty much no one uses it. There are much newer java technologies available that you should check out.

Comment: @Isaac - oftentimes these questions come from individuals who have been "told" what to use and don't have the luxury of "choosing".

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, that's exactly my case!

Comment: I haven't answered here because the issue you have is difficult to explain. But let me try this. It appears you've confused the idea that writing a JavaScript `while` loop will allow your Java code to iterate over the `BufferReader`. That cannot work that way. You must iterate within your Java code in order to iterate over a `BufferedReader` that Java owns.

Comment: You code is mix of JavaScript and JSP code, thus the key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Well, that was actually pretty easy to understand. Now I see where the problem was. Thank you very much, it really helped me fix this. Cheers.